Can Orthodox Jews Eat Food That was Baked on a Nonkosher Baking Sheet with two Layers of Aluminium Foil Over it
If a baking sheet that has been used to cook non-kosher food is used to for example bake cookies, would those cookies be kosher assuming that the cookie dough has a valid kosher symbol and two layers of aluminium foil are put between the dough and the pan? I heard that food that is double-wrapped in aluminium foil can be cooked in a non-kosher oven, and was wondering if a pan’s nonkosher-ness can be offset with foil also.

If you're going to the lengths of kashering your oven, how hard can it be to find a disposable baking sheet?

If you leave the baking pan in the oven while you're kashering it, the heat will kasher the pan at the same time. Though it might also scorch it. At any rate a $3 disposable aluminium baking tray will probably cost less than the amount of aluminium foil you propose using

@LJ5 your question is likely to voted closed as in its current iteration it appears to be a solicitation for personalized advice, which this forum is not for. If you edit the question to remove the second paragraph it is more likely to remain open and/or be voted re-opened.

@Deutronomy Thanks for the heads up, I’ll change it. To answer the other comments the idea is to host a group that includes an Orthodox Jew regularly/keep the oven kosher as long as possible, and I can’t write the Hebrew username but thanks for the hack about kashering the pan, I’ll try to figure out if it’ll scorch.

The best idea is to ask the particular Jew you'd cook for what he'd be ok with

Yeah probably, the dream was to  be hospitable and avoid the whole “oh, no, you don’t have to do that” conversation, but the more I read the more I realize I’m in over my head. Thanks anyways
